# Algolia exception filters: Unexpected token string(to) expected ')'

Tags: android, algolia

I am trying to perform filtering in my Android app using Algolia as they have shown in their [Filtering and facets tutorial](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/filtering-faceting/) but I am getting this error in my `query.setFilters()` method: `Algolia exception filters: Unexpected token string(to) expected ')'`

Here is the code sample I used:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.setAttributesToHighlight("type");
query.setHighlightPreTag("<p style=\"color:red\">");
query.setHighlightPostTag("</p>");
query.setRestrictSearchableAttributes("type","price");
query.setFilters("code=1 AND (price:1000 to 300000000 OR price:10 to 100)");
```

My aim is to perform a range search on my data. 
How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippet in the tutorial had a typo, filter keywords should be in all caps as you can see in the [Filter Syntax list of keywords](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/android/parameters/#filters).

You should use this instead:

```
query.setFilters("code=1 AND (price:1000 TO 300000000 OR price:10 TO 100)");
```

Comment: sincerely speaking, I never knew that.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you @PLNech.